# What is the main use and purpose of Upgraded Standard Token?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, tokens, upgrading

```
contract StandardToken is BasicToken, ERC20 {

mapping (address => mapping (address => uint)) public allowed;

uint public constant MAX_UINT = 2**256 - 1;

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public onlyPayloadSize(3 * 32) {
    uint _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    uint fee = (_value.mul(basisPointsRate)).div(10000); //because 10000 Basis Points == 100% percentage terms
    if (fee > maximumFee) {
        fee = maximumFee;
    }
    if (_allowance < MAX_UINT) {
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
    }
    uint sendAmount = _value.sub(fee);
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(sendAmount);
    if (fee > 0) {
        balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(fee);
        emit Transfer(_from, owner, fee);
    }
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, sendAmount);
}

function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) {


    require(!((_value != 0) && (allowed[msg.sender][_spender] != 0)));

    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
 }

 }

contract UpgradedStandardToken is StandardToken{

function transferByLegacy(address from, address to, uint value) public;
function transferFromByLegacy(address sender, address from, address spender, uint value) public;

function approveByLegacy(address from, address spender, uint value) public;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose which i think is to make the contract backward compatible with `ERC20` while having your own `transfer` and `transferfrom` with custom business logic.